# Import photos in QGIS

Tags: qgis, import, photos

I tried importing by "Import photos" plugin but seems photos have to be tagged before import. I hoped this could be done after import in QGIS.

Now since I have untagged photos there is ofcourse ways to tag them in with range of tools, before importing. But would it be possible to import untagged photos to QGIS directly and then do tagging in QGIS self?

Comment: You want to add exif coordinates to each photo? Why do you want to do it in QGIS?

Comment: Because in QGIS you can click on a map, or snap to another data layer? Having a "this photo is *here*" function in a GIS seems appropriate.

Comment: If it is possible to georeffere outside QGIS why would it be possible to georeffere inside QGIs ? And have a repository of photos inside project itself which are refferenced if needed

Comment: As a workaround you could create a point layer with an attribute where you store the filename. Then digitize the points and attribute, and use python (or some other way) outside QGIS to read the coordinates and attribute and store in each image.